# convert rows to columns in MDX SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Fact Employee Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
      * 
        [Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON ROWS
FROM [People Dashboard];
```

result of the query:
[image]

for some reason i need to convert Emp Type into columns so it become like this:

Year | Quarter | Month | Date | DAILY WORKER | KONTRAK | MTP | MAGANG | PERCOBAAN | TETAP
CY2016 | Third | July | 2016-07-11| 1134 | 4584 | 56 |  331 | 4 | 8391

how to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DAILY WORKER] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[DAILY WORKER]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[KONTRAK] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[KONTRAK]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MTP] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[MTP]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MAGANG] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[MAGANG]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[PERCOBAAN] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[PERCOBAAN]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[TETAP] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Fact Employee Count]
     ,[Dim Emp Type].[Hierarchy].[Emp Type].[TETAP]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[DAILY WORKER]
     ,[Measures].[KONTRAK]
     ,[Measures].[MTP]
     ,[Measures].[MAGANG]
     ,[Measures].[PERCOBAAN]
     ,[Measures].[TETAP]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON 1
FROM [People Dashboard];
```